# Why does an Angular model prevent a checkbox from being checked by default?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I'm using Angularjs for a website and I now want to use a checkbox. I first created a checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

I can of course remove and add `checked` to my liking to have it checked by default or not. I now add a model to it (the model is not defined in the controller yet):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="settings.mySwitch" checked>
```

The checkbox still displays, but all of a sudden the `checked` has no effect at all anymore; the checkbox is always unchecked by default.

Why oh why does the model prevent the `checked` from having any effect? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Instead use `ng-checked` like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="settings.mySwitch" ng-checked="true">
```

Edit: @PSL is right you should be using `ng-init` instead as it will mess up your `ng-model`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-init="settings.mySwitch=true" ng-model="settings.mySwitch" />
```

Comment: You should not mix them, it will mess up initial state of ng-model. See the demo in my answer,

Comment: That works indeed. Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I also use the bootstrap switch (https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch) with the angualr directive for it (https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-switch), and when I now add `bs-switch` to the input `ng-checked="true"` has again no effect. Any ideas how to solve this as well?

Comment: @H_C because [bs-switch must be working on the ng-model](https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-switch/blob/develop/src/directives/bsSwitch.js#L165)..., Better practice is to set the ng-model instead of ng-checked.

Comment: @PSL you are right. thanks :) H_C, you should use `ng-init` for this purpose.

Comment: @Zee You updated your answer and invalidated mine ;) !! However ng-init is also not a good practice as it is not designed for that (i mentioned it in brackets).  read the first red block in [ng-init doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) Though it will still work  better way would be to instantiate in controller.

Comment: @Zee haha i was kidding.. but got a vote in the process which i'l take :D.. thx!!

Answer (score 4):

That is because when as the element is rendered browser sets `checked` property but then angular processes ng-model on the check box (whose value is falsy) and it gets unchecked. Instead if you do `ng-checked="true"` it will work (because `ng-checked` directive sets the property after ng-model is processed as its priority is lower than `ng-model`). *But your model's initial state will get messed up (if using 1.3.x+), as `ng-checked` will not update the state of ng-model*. So just set the `ng-model` value to true instead.

Just for demonstration i am using `ng-init` (You should set the ng-model initial value in the controller instead).

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-init="settings.mySwitch=true" ng-model="settings.mySwitch" />
```

See Demo with comparison:-

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
   <p> With ng-checked {{settings.mySwitch}}
   <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true" ng-model="settings.mySwitch" />  
   <p> WIth Proper Initialization {{settings.mySwitch1}}
   <input type="checkbox" ng-init="settings.mySwitch1=true" ng-model="settings.mySwitch1" />  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the initial value of `settings.mySwitch`. If you want the checkbox to be checked by default then instead of adding `checked` property you should set the initial value to `true` because when angular processes the template it will get its value and render the checked property accordingly.